# Emscripten With Configure Script Says `long long` is Not Available

Tags: cross-compiling, configure, webassembly, emscripten, long-long

When using `emconfigure` to configure [ECL](https://common-lisp.net/project/ecl/) for WebAssembly, the configure script reports:

```
checking size of long long... not available
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking appropiate type for fixnums... configure: error: There is no appropiate integer type for the cl_fixnum type
```

I compiled a minimal C program that used a `long long` with `emcc` and confirmed that it does support it. Why does the configure script detect `long long`s as unavailable?

Answer (score 0):

[`configure` uses a file to get a result](https://gitlab.com/embeddable-common-lisp/ecl/-/blob/develop/src/configure#L7602), but Emscripten doesn't write to local file system by default.

It would better to port it as some kind of [cross compile](https://gitlab.com/embeddable-common-lisp/ecl/-/blob/develop/src/configure#L5018).